# how to take average of duplicate values from two columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         Time    Amplitudes
241241  10.94   6.855957e-01
241240  10.94   6.785480e-01
521497  23.65   6.546916e-01
241339  10.95   6.538565e-01
521496  23.65   6.527822e-01
241340  10.95   6.520147e-01
```

I want to take the average of the duplicate values each in the amplitudes based on the time duplicates so  that we have a single time without duplicate.

I have used this:

```
new_df = amp.groupby('Time', as_index=False).mean()
```

This uses the total length of the dataset to calculate the mean. I want it to use length based on the duplicate values to calculate the average. For example, on the "Time" column 10.94 appears twice, take the average based on that and like that for others

Expected outputs:

```
 Time    Amplitudes
10.94   68207185e-01
23.65   6.537369e-01
10.95   6.529356e-01
```

Comment: with `groupby` as in your question should work. It does not use the total length of the dataframe to calculate the mean, but jut for those rows in each group (with same time).

Comment: ok, but the answer i got is different when i check for the value of time that correspond with 10.94

Comment: The average of  0.685596 and 0.678548 is 0.682072, which is exactly the same in your expected output.

Comment: Look at what i got        
by using group by on my entire dataframe      
1094   | 10.94   | (-0.003873) instead of this 0.682072

Comment: Probably you have other amplitudes in your dataframe at time 10.94, and not just the two  shown in  your example

Comment: let me confirm again, cos i already sorted my dataframe to give me the highest based on the amplitude, and that 10.94 is a particular timeframe in an audio file that can't exits more than 5 at most

Comment: Thank you, you are right, i think i have nothing to bother about again